# ASP.NET calendar shows 6 weeks, how can i make it display 5?

Tags: asp.net

The default asp.net calendar renders with 6 displayable weeks, the last week is always the 'next' month and i dont care about it.  Is there a way to display only 5 weeks?

Answer (score 0):

I've done quite a bit of work with it as of late and I don't think so. It's a very limited calendar.  I've been looking at [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) as an alternative.

Edit, you can make days out side of the current month unselectable on the dayrender event, or even better.  Assign a css class that hides the contents of days outside of the current month

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and is seems to look ok. It does not actually remove the week but blanks the day out.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date.Month != this.Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month) {
        e.Cell.Text="&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

And the output. It's not a perfect solution but it does the trick.

[See Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVfQE.png)